# CStateFlow collector only collecting when view is in TabView with Kotlin Multiplatform in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm working on an app in Kotlin Multipatform with SwiftUI and encountered a strange problem. I have these 2 different views: AddressView & SignatureView which behave differently. When editing a field an event is sent to the ViewModel & it updates a StateFlow with the new data.

The problem is that in AddressView the subscribe gets correctly triggered and updates the UI, while in SignatureView it only triggers once and is no longer triggered after.

Can anyone help me and point me in the right direction?

I omitted as much as possible for readability.

Code for SignatureView:

```
@MainActor class IOSCertificateSignatureViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let viewModel: CertificateSignatureViewModel
    
    @Published var state: SignatureState
    
    private var handle: IOSDisposableHandle?
    
    init(certificate: CoolCertificateDTO) {
        self.viewModel = CertificateSignatureViewModel(
            repository: Repository(databaseDriverFactory: DatabaseDriverFactory()),
            coroutineScope: nil,
            certificate: certificate
        )
        
        self.state = SignatureState(
            signature: certificate.signature ?? CoolSignatureDTO(signeeMail: nil),
            signTechnician: false,
            signSignee: false
        )
    }
    
    func onEvent(event: SignatureEvent) {
        self.viewModel.onEvent(event: event)
    }
    
    func startObserving() {
        handle = viewModel.state.subscribe(onCollect: { state in
            if let state = state {
                self.state = state
            }
        })
    }
    
    func dispose() {
        handle?.dispose()
    }
}


struct CertificateSignatureView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: IOSCertificateSignatureViewModel
    
    init(certificate: CoolCertificateDTO) {
        viewModel = IOSCertificateSignatureViewModel(certificate: certificate)
    }
    
    @State var timer = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MaterialTextFieldView(
                text: Binding(
                    get: { return viewModel.state.signature.signeeMail ?? "" },
                    set: {
                        viewModel.onEvent(event: SignatureEvent.SigneeMailModified(value: $0))
                    }
                ),
                label: Translations.companion.getTranslations().signatureSigneeMail
            )
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.startObserving()
            
        }
        .onDisappear {
            viewModel.dispose()
        }
    }
}
```

Code for AddressView (which works):

```
@MainActor class IOSCertificateAddressesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let viewModel: CertificateAddressViewModel
    
    @Published var state: AddressState
    
    private var handle: IOSDisposableHandle?
    
    init(certificate: CoolCertificateDTO) {
        self.viewModel = CertificateAddressViewModel(
            repository: Repository(databaseDriverFactory: DatabaseDriverFactory()),
            coroutineScope: nil,
            coolCertificateDTO: certificate
        )
        
        self.state = AddressState(
            billingAddress: certificate.billingAddress!,
            installAddress: certificate.installationAddress!
        )
    }

    func onEvent(event: AddressEvent) {
        self.viewModel.onEvent(event: event)
    }

    func startObserving() {
        handle = viewModel.state.subscribe(onCollect: { state in
            if let state = state {
                self.state = state
            }
        })
    }

    func dispose() {
        handle?.dispose()
    }
}

struct CertificateAddressesView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: IOSCertificateAddressesViewModel
    
    init(certificate: CoolCertificateDTO) {
        viewModel = IOSCertificateAddressesViewModel(certificate: certificate)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MaterialTextFieldView(
                text: Binding(
                    get: { return viewModel.state.getCorrectAddress(type: type).street ?? "" },
                    set: { viewModel.onEvent(event: AddressEvent.AddressStreetModified(value: $0, type: type)) }
                ),
                label: Translations.companion.getTranslations().addressStreet
            )
        }
        .background(PenguinVariables.whiteBackground)
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.startObserving()
        }
        .onDisappear {
            viewModel.dispose()
        }
    }
}
```

AddressViewModel:

```
data class AddressState(
    val billingAddress: CoolAddressDTO,
    val installAddress: CoolAddressDTO
) {
    fun getCorrectAddress(type: Int): CoolAddressDTO {
        return if (type == CoolAddressDTO.TYPE_INSTALLATION) {
            installAddress
        } else {
            billingAddress
        }
    }
}

sealed class AddressEvent {
    data class AddressStreetModified(val value: String, val type: Int): AddressEvent()
}
class CertificateAddressViewModel(
    private val repository: ICoolRepository,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope? = null,
    coolCertificateDTO: CoolCertificateDTO
) {
    private val viewModelScope = coroutineScope ?: CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(AddressState(
        coolCertificateDTO.billingAddress ?: CoolAddressDTO(),
        coolCertificateDTO.installationAddress ?: CoolAddressDTO()
    ))
    val state = _state.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(10000),
        initialValue = null
    ).toCommonStateFlow()

    fun onEvent(event: AddressEvent) {
        when (event) {
            
            is AddressEvent.AddressStreetModified -> {
                val currentAddressState = if (event.type == CoolAddressDTO.TYPE_BILLING) _state.value.billingAddress else _state.value.installAddress
                _state.update {
                    if (event.type == CoolAddressDTO.TYPE_BILLING) {
                        it.copy(billingAddress = currentAddressState.copy(street = event.value))
                    } else {
                        it.copy(installAddress = currentAddressState.copy(street = event.value))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SignatureViewModel:

```
data class SignatureState(
    val signature: CoolSignatureDTO,
    val signTechnician: Boolean = false,
    val signSignee: Boolean = false
) {
    fun shouldShowSign() = signTechnician || signSignee
}

sealed class SignatureEvent {

    data class SigneeMailModified(val value: String): SignatureEvent()
  
}
class CertificateSignatureViewModel(
    private val repository: ICoolRepository,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope? = null,
    certificate: CoolCertificateDTO
) {
    private val viewModelScope = coroutineScope ?: CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(
        SignatureState(
            signature = certificate.signature ?: CoolSignatureDTO()
        )
    )
    val state = _state.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(10000),
        initialValue = null
    ).toCommonStateFlow()
    fun onEvent(event: SignatureEvent) {
        when (event) {
            
            is SignatureEvent.SigneeMailModified -> {
                val signature = _state.value.signature
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(signature = signature.copy(signeeMail = event.value))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for CommonStateFlow:

```
expect open class CommonStateFlow<T>(flow: StateFlow<T>): StateFlow<T>

fun <T> StateFlow<T>.toCommonStateFlow() = CommonStateFlow(this)

actual open class CommonStateFlow<T> actual constructor(
    private val flow: StateFlow<T>
): StateFlow<T> by flow


actual open class CommonStateFlow<T> actual constructor(
    private val flow: StateFlow<T>
): CommonFlow<T>(flow), StateFlow<T> {
    override val replayCache: List<T>
        get() = flow.replayCache

    override val value: T
        get() = flow.value

    override suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<T>): Nothing {
        flow.collect(collector)
    }
}


actual open class CommonFlow<T> actual constructor(
    private val flow: Flow<T>
): Flow<T> by flow {
    //Collects values emitted by the flow
    fun subscribe(
        coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
        dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
        onCollect: (T) -> Unit
    ): IOSDisposableHandle {
        val job = coroutineScope.launch(dispatcher) {
            flow.collect(onCollect)
        }

        return IOSDisposableHandle {
            job.cancel()
        }
    }

    //Shorthand
    @OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
    fun subscribe(
        onCollect: (T) -> Unit
    ): IOSDisposableHandle {
        return subscribe(
            coroutineScope = GlobalScope,
            dispatcher = Dispatchers.Main,
            onCollect = onCollect
        )
    }
}
```

IOSDisposableHandle:

```
fun interface IOSDisposableHandle: DisposableHandle
```

**EDIT:** So I've been trying multiple things and one thing that seems to make the emits happen is when I put a TabView around the items. Does anyone know why?